# Msfpayload: Exe within an exe?

Tags: kali-linux, backdoor

So you can use msfpayload or msfvenom to add a payload to an existing exe, most people online seem to use reverse shell. But I was wondering if you could include a custom exe of your own design as a payload. For example, I have "evil_notepad.exe" that I want to add a payload "showanalert.exe". When opened, "showanalert.exe" will be run.

I tried using the command: msfvenom -p generic/custom -f exe -k -x notepad.exe PAYLOADFILE=showanalert.exe  >evil_notepad.exe

Which seemed to work, but caused the program itself to crash when run. 
(Which also makes me feel I have made a mistake somewhere.)

Any ideas?

EDIT: Also tried using STDIN for "custom payloads" but whatever I try is apparently an "invalid custom payload"...

Comment: Maybe try Yab instead? It has a nice GUI (considering what it does), and it works with Windows (which, to be honest, I tend to favor).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that you can use your own payload, but that payload has to play nicely with the host exe.

There are numerous [tutorials](http://www.scriptjunkie.us/2011/08/custom-payloads-in-metasploit-4/) that I encourage you to look at.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question well but if you want to hide a backdoor on notepad and u don't wana use meterpreter or reverse shell then use  a packer app which can hide your backdoor on a notepad and when the user runs the notepad the packer upacks it self and runs the backdoor.